# calendar day render not working in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I created a calender with render option. It works perfectly on my local machine but it does not work on the server. I showed employee time sheet in a calender its working fine in local machine. But now i am published on the server its not working there.

My partial code is here:

```
if (e.Day.Date.Month == DateTime.Now.Month - 1)
{
    if ((lblfromdate.Text != "") && (lbltodate.Text != ""))
    {
        if (e.Day.Date < Convert.ToDateTime(lblfromdate.Text))
        {
            e.Cell.Text = string.Empty;
            e.Cell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getallholidayinfoTableAdapter TA = new DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getallholidayinfoTableAdapter();
            DataSet4.sp_getallholidayinfoDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
            if (DS.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataView DV = new DataView();
                DV = DS.DefaultView;
                string fromdate = Convert.ToString(lblfromdate.Text.Substring(5, 2) + "-" + lblfromdate.Text.Substring(8, 2) + "-" + lblfromdate.Text.Substring(0, 4));
                string todate = Convert.ToString(lbltodate.Text.Substring(5, 2) + "-" + lbltodate.Text.Substring(8, 2) + "-" + lbltodate.Text.Substring(0, 4));
                DV.RowFilter = "fldfromdate >=#" + fromdate + "# and fldfromdate <=#" + todate + "#";
                if (DV.Count > 0)
                {
                    string indate = Convert.ToString(DV[0]["fldfromdate"]);
                    string input = indate.Substring(6) + "-" + indate.Substring(0, 2) + "-" + indate.Substring(3, 2);
                    if (Convert.ToString(e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()) == input)
                    {
                        e.Cell.Controls.Clear();
                        e.Cell.Text = "Holiday";
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My design code:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" BackColor="White"
    BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="2px" Enabled="False"
    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black"
    Height="183px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" ShowGridLines="True"
    Width="659px" OnDayRender="Calendar2_DayRender" ShowNextPrevMonth="False">

    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#6699FF" BorderStyle="Solid"
        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />

    <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt"
        ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />

    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />

    <SelectedDayStyle ForeColor="White" />

    <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="None"
        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399" />

</asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: "its not working there" is rather unusable as a description. What exactly happens/doesn't happen? Error message, content just not rendered, just wrong format?

Comment: I post my partial code only. am having more than 2000 lines in my code..

Comment: Please tell us what "is not working". Are you receiving an server side error (500)? Is the date/date range not as you are expecting? You shouldn't need 2000 LOC just to display a calender. It looks like you want to colorize days as holidays and those days are read from a database. Did you already check if the data you read from the database is correct/as you expect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the Regional settings on the server compared to your development server.

Usually when you are building dates as strings from strings, and then your servers change from one region to another, there will be problems with date formats

So if you are building a string for "dd-MM-yyyy" then the server might be looking for "MM-dd-yyyy"